# Internel Server Error 500 with Jersey and Hibernate OneToMany Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jersey

I am making a project using Hibernate and Jersey and recieving `500 Internel Server error` when I try to get a resource with Hibernate OneToMany Mapping at its back. I am using Apache TomCat for deployment. The details are as under.

There are two Model Classes with OneToMany Relationship. `Category` and `Book`, Category can have multiple Books. The POST request is working fine, But when I try to get books using following URL, 500 Internal Server occurs. I am unable to find cause and don't know what I am doing wrong because I have made a check on returning the resource to Jersey, the resource object seems perfectly fine. 
Please help me in

- Finding the cause and solving the problem.
- How to debug this 500
  Internal Server when there is No error/ exception is given. I have
  tried running the server in debug mode but no use.

The API URLs are.

```
/webapi/category/{categoryID}/books
/webapi/category/{categoryID}/books/{bookID}
```

The code of the classes is given below.

**The Model Classes**

This is Category Class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int categoryID;
    private String categoryName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Book> Book = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Category(){

    }

    // Getters and Setters    
}
```

This is Book Class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int bookID;
    private String bookName;
    private String bookAuthor;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Category_ID")
    private Category category;

    //getter  and setters
}
```

**The DAO Classes used to get data using Hibernate from database.**
This is CateogryDAO.

```
public class CategoryDAO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Category> categoryList = (List<Category>)session.createQuery("from Category").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return categoryList;
    }

    public Category addCategory(Category cat) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // for updating existing labels and creating new ones
        session.persist(cat);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return cat;//changing also return type

    }

    public Category updateCategory( Category cat) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // for updating existing labels and creating new ones
        session.update(cat);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return cat;//changing also return type
    }

    public Category getCategoryById(int categoryID) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Category category = (Category) session.get(Category.class, categoryID);
        System.out.println("CATDAO"+ category.getCategoryName());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return category;
    }

    public void removeCategory(Category category) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(category);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

This is BookDAO Class.

```
public class BookDAO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Book> getBooksList(int categoryID) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE Category_ID ="+ categoryID;
        System.out.println(sql);
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(Book.class);

        List<Book> bookList = query.list();
        System.out.println(bookList.get(0).getBookAuthor());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return bookList;
    }

    public Book addBook(Book book) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // for updating existing labels and creating new ones
        session.persist(book);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return book;// changing also return type

    }

    public Book updateBook(Book book) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // for updating existing labels and creating new ones
        session.update(book);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return book;// changing also return type
    }

    public Book getBookById(int bookID) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Book book = (Book) session.get(Book.class, bookID);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return book;
    }

    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(book);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

}
```

**The Jersey resource classes.**

The Category Resource Class.

```
@Path("/category")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CategoryResource {

    CategoryDAO catdao = new CategoryDAO();

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }

    @GET
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        System.out.println("Getting All Categories");
        List<Category> catlist = catdao.getCategoryList();
        for (Category tempcat : catlist) {

            System.out.println(tempcat.getCategoryName());
            List<Book> booklist = tempcat.getBook();
            for (Book book : booklist) {
                System.out.println(book.getBookName());
            }
        }



        return catlist;
    }

    // to get a single book for this LinksGetter is used
    @GET
    @Path("/{categoryID}")
    public Response getCategoryById(@PathParam("categoryID") int categoryID, @Context UriInfo caturiInfo) {
        System.out.println("Category ID = " + categoryID);
        Category category = catdao.getCategoryById(categoryID);
        String catselfUrl = LinksGetter.getLinkForSelfCategory(caturiInfo, category);
        category.addcatLink(catselfUrl, "self");
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(category).build();
    }

    @POST
    public Category addCategory(Category category) {
        return catdao.addCategory(category);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{categoryID}") // --->http://localhost:8080/helloworld/webapi/category/2
    public Category updateCategory(@PathParam("categoryID") int categoryID, Category category) {
        category.setCategoryID(categoryID);
        return catdao.updateCategory(category);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{categoryID}")
    public void deleteCategory(@PathParam("categoryID") int categoryID) {
        Category category = catdao.getCategoryById(categoryID);
        catdao.removeCategory(category);
    }

    //we dont use GET POST because we want it for every request
    @Path("/{categoryID}/books")
    public BookResource getBookResource() {
        return new BookResource();
    }
}
```

This is Book Resource Class.

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BookResource {

    BookDAO bookdao = new BookDAO();
    CategoryDAO catdao = new CategoryDAO();

    @GET
    public List<Book> getBooks(@PathParam("categoryID") int categoryID) {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        System.out.println("Getting Books");
        List<Book> books = null;
        books = bookdao.getBooksList(categoryID);
        System.out.println(books.get(0).getCategory().getCategoryName()); 
        return books;
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/{bookID}")
        public Response getBookById(@PathParam("bookID") int bookID, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
            Book book = bookdao.getBookById(bookID);
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            String selfUrl = LinksGetter.getLinkForSelfBook(uriInfo, book);
            book.addLink(selfUrl, "self");
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(book).build();
    }

    @POST
    public Book addBook(@PathParam("categoryID") int categoryID, Book book) {
        Category category=catdao.getCategoryById(categoryID);
        book.setCategory(category);
        return bookdao.addBook(book);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{bookID}")
    public Book updateBook(@PathParam("bookID") int bookID, Book book){
        book.setBookID(bookID);
        return bookdao.updateBook(book);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{bookID}")
    public void deleteBook(@PathParam("bookID") int bookID) {
        System.out.println("Deleting Book");
        Book book = bookdao.getBookById(bookID);
        bookdao.removeBook(book);
    }
}
```

This is the consol logs when i run the server

```
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:helloworld' did not find a matching property.
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1089 ms
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 24, 2016 1:52:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
Mar 24, 2016 1:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 24, 2016 1:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 24, 2016 1:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3890 ms
```

Comment: Please provide `catalina.out` logs from the tomcat server

Comment: Check it now. I have added the "Catalina".

Comment: Wrong file.  The server that is hosting tomcat will have a file called `catalina.out` which is tomcat's main logging file.  The 500 error should have made a stack trace in that file.

Comment: I am using Apache tomcat on windows 7, which only uses console appender for catalina.out logs. 

The same logs are appended to eclipse console, which are added in the question.

Comment: There is no error in cataling/apache logs, it seems perfectly fine, But I think there is some issue with Marshalling/ De marshalling of JSON. I am trying to figure it out, but i need guidance